# Return All Rows With Particular Value In Different Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause, having

I have a table which looks like this

```
Time            Master_Price    Discounted_price1   Discounted_qty1 Discounted_price2   Discounted_qty2 Discounted_price3   Discounted_qty3
1552279758      100                     90                  5               80                  10              70              15
1552279759      200                     195                 6               185                 7               80              12
1552279760      300                     285                 11              200                 9               150             7
1552279761      400                     300                 20              250                 25              220             30
1552279763      500                     400                 30              350                 5               300             8
1552279766      500                     400                 NULL            350                 9               300             9
```

The Time column is unique which is in unix format.

Requirement is to use arithmatical operation on the Master_Price column and check which Discounted Price matches with it and return the corresponding Discounted Qty.

Suppose if Master_Price is 100 and I enter Master_Price - 20 then the value 12(present in the second row) should be returned or the entire row.
If the Master_Price is 200 and I enter Master_Price - 50 then the value 7(present in the third row) should be returned or the entire row and so on.
If the Master_Price is 500 and I enter Master_Price - 100 then it should return 30 or the entire row and but not the row which has NULL

The option to enter the integer number to subtract from Master_Price should be in the query. It is ok even if it is hardcoded

Comment: I think i almost have this worked out for you, but I'm confused. Based on your explanation (or my understanding of it), if Master_Price is 100, and you want Master_Price - 20, it should return 10, not 12. Row 2 has a Master Price of 200, so if its 100, and 80 (100-20), then it would find discount2 in row 1, and return discount_qty_2.  Let me know if i'm misunderstanding your logic.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above, but i think this query should work:

(It doesn't get the whole row if it doesn't find any.)

```
select @MP := 500;
select @DISCOUNT := 100;
select 
CASE
    WHEN Discounted_price1 = Master_Price - @DISCOUNT THEN Discounted_qty1 
    WHEN Discounted_price2 = Master_Price - @DISCOUNT THEN Discounted_qty2 
    WHEN Discounted_price3 = Master_Price - @DISCOUNT THEN Discounted_qty3 
ELSE 'None'
END as qty
from prices where Master_Price = @MP and ((Discounted_price1 = Master_Price - @DISCOUNT and Discounted_qty1 >=0) or (Discounted_price2 = Master_Price - @DISCOUNT and Discounted_qty2 >=0) or (Discounted_price3 = Master_Price - @DISCOUNT  and Discounted_qty3 >=0));
```

I've made a fiddle to demonstrate/play with it.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0166cc/16